# Is it safe to delete the files under /var/lib/azsec ? Azure VM

Tags: azure, logging, server, centos, azure-virtual-machine

I logged to my CentOS 7 server ( Azure Virtual machine) this morning and found that it's running slow on space, so I'm looking for undesired log files and safe to remove files, so Is it safe to delete the files under /var/lib/azsec ? 
Here's a screenshot of the folder:
[/var/lib/ folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsLfW.png)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not safe to do that directly because if you want to check the log to find something indeed later and there will no log to find.

So I suggest you can make a backup of the log and store it in another place. Then you can delete it from the VM to make some space to use.

Comment: The thing is I don't need any of that log, and it's getting bigger and bigger in size, So I have to address this issue sooner or later. Anyhow I'll do as you suggested, I'll make a copy of the files and delete and see if anything happens.
Thank for the information.